# Problemas al crear funciones en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando crear la siguiente funcion en MySQL Workbench:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `capturar_consecutivo`() 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE num INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET num = ( select * from consecutivo);
    RETURN num;
END
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

pero el sistema me arroja un error:

> Error Code: 1418. This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

y la verdad no entiendo a que se debe ya que si la ejecuto en un localhost y el sistema me la toma correctamente, pero en Workbench no me lo toma. ¿Alguien puede decirme si la sintaxis es correcta?

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que leas [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26015334/5213794)  pregunta