# Error al crear una función en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**Aclaraciones:**

1- Independientemente de lo que haga la función, sólo me interesa hacerla funcionar.

2- No está terminada, ya que el parámetro "tabla" se recibe pero no se usa.

3- El hecho de no retornar nada dentro del `IF` no implica que sea la causa del error, es decir, si reemplazamos la línea `ALTER TABLE`action`ADD`company_id`int(11) NOT NULL;` por `RETURN 1;` tampoco funcionará.

¿Cuál es el problema? Me da error 1064 en *MySQL Workbench*.

**Error completo:**

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 10

```
CREATE FUNCTION `createColumn`(tabla varchar(50))
RETURNS TINYINT(1)
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT count(*)
            FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
            WHERE `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.`table_name` = `action`
            AND `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.`table_schema` = `testdb_dev`
            AND `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.`column_name` = `company_id`)  THEN

  ALTER TABLE `action` ADD `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL;

RETURN 1;
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

A través del chat de este sitio me proporcionaron el siguiente enlace:  [Enlace a otra pregunta de stack](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194709/problemas-al-crear-funciones-en-mysql/213988#213988), dentro de esa pregunta se puede apreciar este otro enlace: [Enlace a otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015160/deterministic-no-sql-or-reads-sql-data-in-its-declaration-and-binary-logging-i/26015334#26015334) y por último dentro de este se puede apreciar uno hacia la web oficial: [Web oficial de MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html)

Resumen:

Lo he podido solucionar siguiente 3 pasos:

1- ejecutando la sentencia: `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;` tal y como se puede apreciar en el segundo y tercer enlace.

2- añadiendo `DETERMINISTIC` después de `RETURNS`, de la misma forma que se puede apreciar en el segundo y tercer enlace.

3- añadiendo `DELIMITER $$` al inicio y `$$ DELIMITER ;` al final, como se puede apreciar en el primer enlace.

Resultado de prueba:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION f1(i INT)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  RETURN i;
END;
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi parecer el error que te sale es que el return de tu función esta dentro de una condición IF, algo asi como que obligas a que siempre se cumpla la condicion para que obtengas un return, podrias intentar colocando el return de tu funcion despues de finalizar el IF (END IF)o añadir otro  RETURN 1, posterior al END IF.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION `createColumn`(tabla varchar(50))
 RETURNS TINYINT(1)
 BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT count(*)
        FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
        WHERE `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.`table_name` = `action`
        AND `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.`table_schema` = `testdb_dev`
        AND `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.`column_name` = `company_id`)  THEN

        ALTER TABLE `action` ADD `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL;


  END IF;
  RETURN 1;

 END;
```

Acabo de hacer algunas pruebas, comentarte que hice algo similar a lo que pides añadiendo una nueva columna a una tabla, el problema es que solo me funciona como PROCEDURE y no como FUNCTION  en MySql, por si te sirve te comparto el codigo que tengo para que lo adaptes a lo que necesites:

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testing`(IN `nombre_tabla`   VARCHAR(50), IN `nombre_columna` VARCHAR(20), IN `tipo_columna` VARCHAR(20))

 NO SQL
 BEGIN

 SET @ddl = CONCAT('alter table ', nombre_tabla, ' add column (', nombre_columna, ' ',  tipo_columna, ')');

 PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @ddl;
 EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;

 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Ejecucion del Procedure :

CALL testing('action','company_id','int');

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo, el error persiste. Aquí te lo dejo "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10". Siendo la línea 10 "ALTER TABLE `action` ADD `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL;"